# MS SQL Server Date Month Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL will output a month part as a number but I'd like to out put the 3 char version (Jan, Feb, Mar etc)

My query thus far is

```
SELECT  MONTH(dtm_StartDate) AS Month, COUNT(tbl_Bookings.int_BookingID) AS CountOfBookings, 
SUM(tbl_Bookings.int_ToOwner) AS IncomeToOwner
FROM    tbl_Bookings INNER JOIN
        tbl_Properties ON tbl_Bookings.int_PropertyID = tbl_Properties.int_PropertyID INNER JOIN
        tbl_Owners ON tbl_Properties.int_OwnerID = tbl_Owners.int_OwnerID
WHERE   (tbl_Bookings.dtm_StartDate >= '2020-01-01') AND (tbl_Bookings.dtm_StartDate <= '2020-12-31')
AND     tbl_Properties.int_PropertyID = 1
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, tbl_Bookings.dtm_StartDate), 0), MONTH(dtm_StartDate),tbl_Properties.str_PropertyName
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: sorry - done now - MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each DBMS the way is different

Here are few 4 DBMS's

**MS SQL Server**

```
Select Convert(char(3), GetDate(), 0)
```

**MySQL**

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%b') AS Displaydate
```

**Postgresql**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP 'NOW()', 'Mon') AS "Month";
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') FROM dual;
```

So in your case use the appropriate date field instead of current date (which I took as example)

ex. for SQL Server

```
SELECT  Convert(char(3), dtm_StartDate, 0) AS Month, COUNT(tbl_Bookings.int_BookingID) AS CountOfBookings, 
SUM(tbl_Bookings.int_ToOwner) AS IncomeToOwner
FROM    tbl_Boo ....
```

Comment: ok thanks - I then get issues with the grouping - Column 'tbl_Bookings.dtm_StartDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: do the same for the group as well, I mean instead of `MONTH(dtm_StartDate)` put the 
`Convert(char(3), dtm_StartDate, 0) `

Answer (score 1):

This is also very useful for `MS SQL Server`

```
DECLARE @yourdate date = '2020-01-01'
SELECT FORMAT(@yourdate, 'MMM') AS YourDate
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Jan
```

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL would be:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dtm_StartDate, '%b') AS Month
```